# With use PathVariable CSS not loading and how to fill form to update in thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, forms, thymeleaf

I am trying to do same small service and sometimes I am sending requests to my Rest Api.
I am getting two problems:

1. How to fill field in form in html using thymeleaf?  I have form like this and would like to fill fields with current values (th:value="${}" - not working for me):

   `<form th:action="@{/offences/edit}" method="post" th:object="${createOffenceForm}"> <input th:field="*{name}" th:value="${currentOffence.name}"/> <input th:field="*{penaltyPoints}" th:value="${currentOffence.penaltyPoints}"/> <input th:field="*{amountOfFine}"  th:value="${currentOffence.amountOfFine}"/> <button type="submit">UPDATE</button> </form>`
2. The problem is with loading css styles to html when I redirect to the site with path variable. For example i created html with two buttons. First one is hardcoded:

   `<a th:href="@{/offences/test}" class="link" style="text-decoration: none"><button class="buttonOK" type="submit">EDIT</button></a>`

after redirect my site looks like this (everything works, it should be like that):
`
[image: site with normal look]

and here is after second button - redirect with path variable:
`<a th:href="@{'/offences/edit/' + ${offence.id}}" class="link" style="text-decoration: none"><button class="buttonOK" type="submit">EDIT</button></a>`

and view after load:
[image: broken view]

Answer (score 0):

For the issue with your form data not being filled, this is because `th:field` and `th:value` are not meant to be used at the same time. So `th:field` ends up overwriting you value.
In your case I would suggest either manualy setting name (and id) or replacing th:object with the a filled version of the bean you want to return and only using `th:field`

As for the second issue it looks like a faulty fragment return on a post call to me but need to atleast have the controller functions and more complete html to say anything about that. And in general it's advisable to have 1 question per problem and not bundle things.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found soultion.

1. To fill fields in form I only had to add to ModelMap form with fields.
   Something like this and thymeleaf autofilled fields in html.

`modelMap.addAttribute("createOffenceForm", new CreateOffenceForm(offenceDTO.getName(), offenceDTO.getPenaltyPoints(), offenceDTO.getAmountOfFine()));`

2. Second solution is simple too. When changed mapping in Controller from @GetMapping("/path/{id}") to @GetMapping("/path-{id}") - everything works. There is no other problems with styles...